# Как в форму обратной связи добавить вложение?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

У меня есть форма работающая на `phpmailer`, я хотел бы в эту форму добавить функцию загрузки картинок, я посмотрел на гитхабе пример добавления, но все равно когда жму на сабмит, отправляется всего лишь информация, без вложения.

Сама форма выглядит так:

```
 <form id="contactForm" action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="name">ФИО номинанта:</label>
        <input id="name" class="field" name="name" required type="text" placeholder="ФИО">
      </div>
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="message"></label>
        <textarea id="message" class="field" required name="message" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>
      <label for="">Загрузите самое красивое фото номинанта</label>
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"> Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">


        <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="Max">
        </div>
      <div class="field-block">
        <input id="check" name="check" checked type="checkbox">
        <span class="check-text">Даю согласие на обработку данных</span>
      </div>
      <button id="button" class="button" type="submit">Отправить</button>

    </form>
```

Файл обработчик:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/Validator.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/ContactMailer.php';

if (!Validator::isAjax() || !Validator::isPost()) {
    echo 'access denied!';
    exit;
}

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])) : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])) : null;
$company = isset($_POST['company']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['company'])) : null;
$job = isset($_POST['job']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['job'])) : null;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])) : null;
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['message'])) : null;



if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($message)) {
    echo '';
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidEmail($email)) {
    echo 'E-mail error.';
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidPhone($phone)) {
    echo 'Error phone';
    exit;
}

if (ContactMailer::send($name, $email, $phone, $message, $company, $job)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($name) . ', message send succesfully';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: вы хотите с помощью формы отправить файл(каритнку) на сервер и потом вставить его в письмо, я правильно понял?

Comment: мне просто надо отправить картинку на почту, без отправки на сервер

Comment: без отправки на сервер не получется, т к отправка сообщения обрабатывается на стороне сервера. (либо юзануть чегото api)

Comment: `$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <img src="http://bla.jpg" />';` метод класса `PHPMailer`

Comment: у меня просто форма обратной связи, и люди когда регистрируются будут  загружать свои фотографий, и оно должно приходить на мою почту, я почти все перепробовал, но без изменений

Comment: 1) Добавляете в форму `input` с `type=file` 2) Принимаете этот файл на сервере (`в php`). 3) Сохраняете где то на серваке картинку 4) Формируете `body` для сообщения 5) Отправляете сообщение

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Спасибо за ваш ответ, еще один вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда юзер прикреплял картинку, и нажимал на сабмит, оно отправлялось на почту, без никаких сохранении на сервере

Comment: Можно, задействуйте сторонее `api`, которое это сделает за вас. Возможно [поможет](https://toster.ru/q/208369). Сам не юзал, т к все время ручками делаю